# Simulating button presses for build server script

Tags: bash, build-server

I need to install a binary file as part of a build server script. Problem is that it requires accepting a license agreement.

Is it possible to simulate button presses via a bash script?

```
./binary.bin | echo 'q' | echo 'y' | | echo 'e' | | echo 's' | echo '\n'
```

Something along those lines? I know this is, to put it mildly, an inelegant solution, but I'm dealing with a proprietary third-party SDK that is, frankly, driving me nuts. the alternative is to edit almost a hundred library-related files, which I'd rather not.

Comment: I am sure you respect the licence agreement of the package ... Did you take a look inside the bin file? Bash containing binaries sometimes are editable, because the script is included in plain text.

Comment: I would recommend the suggestion above, as that would be the most elegant solution. However systematically you can achieve this with `expect` plenty of guides around.

Comment: @ChristophS Ah, seems like you're right. Thank you!

Comment: OK, so maybe you accept my answer ... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you respect the licence agreement of the package ...

Did you take a look inside the bin file? Bash containing binaries sometimes are editable, because the script is included in plain text. Then fit it to your needs.